# How does Django store it's staicfiles after collectstatic is run?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I need a bit of clarification regarding how Django updates its static files. Here is a hypothetical that will explain my predicament:

- I'm working on my own website which requires a link to a PDF that is stored as a static file.
- Later I replaced this PDF file, with a slightly altered name, and made corrections respectively in my code.
- Then I run the collectstatic command to replace the old static files and everything works as expected. Explorer shows me that the old files have been properly replaced in their respective folders.
- When I go to test the link I'm still forwarded to my old PDF file. *The old staticfile as if nothing has been replaced.*

Can anyone explain to me how this happened? I'm just concerned and a bit freaked out that my old static file is still being referenced.  I mean it could just be a simple typo or I have a haunted static folder on my hands.

Comment: I have not worked with Django in a while, but I think you have `DEBUG=True` in the `settings.py` file. That is why you still get the old pdf, css etc. When you set `DEBUG=False`, your website is in production mode, and so nothing(css, javascript etc) will work. If you set up, say, nginx  and tell it the path to your static folder, you should get the new pdf, css, javascript etc as expected.

Comment: probably you need to look into your html where its pointing to old pdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `collectstatic` command is run Django searches for present static files in `STATICFILES_DIRS` and copies them into `STATIC_ROOT` path.

The link to file that Django returns - is **exactly how it is set in code** - Django **will not** search it this file is present to show the link.

Check or search your code for old file name, maybe it is left somewhere.

Also, static files usually are css, js, images - files used in rendering page. User content, data files (PDF file looks to be one of these) for downloading via download link - should be served as [`MEDIA FILES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/).